# Where ads.txt should be placed in Angular 8 SSR?

Tags: angular, deployment, ads, firebase-hosting, server-side-rendering

I'm using Angular 8 Server-Side-Rendering (SSR) on Firebase Hosting. App is deployed by firebase function. Now I'm struggling how to add ads.txt from Google Adsense and where ads.txt should be placed in my project.

[The project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuCTI.png)

1. I convert app in main directory with **npm run build:ssr**
2. Next I copy converted **dist directory** to functions
3. And finally when **dist** dir appends in functions dir I use **firebase deploy**

If it will be placed in right directory, does 'firebase deploy' will upload ads.txt to main directory?

Maybe I should upload file in another way?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks Stack!

Answer (score 4):

After placing the ads.txt file into your src directory, you need to add the file to the *assets* array in your angular.json file. Then it will be placed into the root of your project after build.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myproject/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/ads.txt",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/assets"
            ],
...
```

Comment: I have localized projects. It does not work for me.
Can you check please my post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318108/how-to-add-app-ads-txt-to-angular-localized-project-on-firebase-hosting

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out through trial and error.

If anyone will stuck on this it is very easy.

1. Convert app with `npm run build:ssr`
2. Copy generated dist dir to `functions` dir
3. Copy ads.txt to `functions/dist/browser`
4. Right now you are ready to deploy your app through `firebase deploy` command
5. After deploy, you can check if ads.txt loaded successfully `http://example.com/ads.txt`

Whole tree should look like this [project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx8LZ.png)