# How to add app-ads.txt to angular localized project on Firebase hosting

Tags: angular, admob, firebase-hosting, app-ads.txt

I added app-ads.txt to *src* folder of my project.

In angular.json added `"src/app-ads.txt"` to `"assets"`, that is:

```
"assets": [
    ....
    "src/app-ads.txt"             
 ],
 ...
```

Next step, I deploy the project to Firebase hosting:

1. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. `firebase login`
3. `firebase init`
4. during init wrote the ***"dist"***
5. `ng build --prod --localize`
6. `firebase deploy`

After command number 5 in *dist* folder has 5 localized projects ([image]).

If open any folder inside has an *app-ads.txt* file ([image]).

But after deploying the file is missing.

How to fix it?

Comment: can you include your firebase.json?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with a similar setup. Double check you firebase.json rules. Here's what mine looks like,

```
{
  "hosting": {
      "public": "dist/{yourapp}",
      "ignore": [
          "firebase.json",
          "**/.*",
          "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [{
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
      }]
  }
}
```